# VB.Net - Count +1 every time when creating a new row in database

Tags: database, vb.net, counter

I want some sort of label that is counting every record that is imported in the database.

Do I need to use a for each loop?

Can someone explain me how to do it, or set me on the right way to do it?

```
With cmd

                .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Workflow ([Import], [DossierPad]) VALUES ('" + Import + "','" + Pad + "')"
                .ExecuteNonQuery()

                .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Data ([DossierPad], [Tif], [Grootte]) VALUES ('" + Pad + "','" + stukjes(0) + "','" + stukjes(2) + "')"
                .ExecuteNonQuery()

                If Tifcheck(Tif) = False Then
                    cmd.CommandText = "Update Data Set Tif = '" & Tif & "' WHERE Tif="
                ElseIf Tifcheck(Tif) = True Then

                End If

                If stukjes(2) < 20000 Then
                    .CommandText = "UPDATE Data SET Blanco = '" & blanco & "' WHERE DossierPad = '" & Pad & "'"
                    .ExecuteNonQuery()
                Else
                    .CommandText = "UPDATE Data SET Blanco = '" & blanco1 & "' WHERE DossierPad = '" & Pad & "'"
                    .ExecuteNonQuery()
                End If

End With
```

This is the part of code where I insert records in my database.
Now my question is how can I get a label to count every record in the database while it is intering.

Comment: We need more information to give you an answer.

Comment: could you please post the code where you insert to your database

Comment: Made an edit to my post. @Mederic

Comment: I know I don't use parametrized queries, I had them but needed to remove the for some reason, at least that is what my boss was saying. (It was not relevant for the assignment)

Comment: Well here you only insert 2 rows why you want to count them?

Comment: intCursor += 1 everytime you insert.

Comment: @Mederic this piece of code is in a loop, my boss wants to see how far the insert is going, couse it would be a program which needs to import very big documents to a database.

Comment: put a global variable as integer and before `end with` do `myint += 2`

Comment: Like this `Dim myint As Int32` and `End If myint += 2 End With`

Comment: @Klaas-JelleRas yeah but make sure Dim is in a global place outside of a sub

Comment: @Mederic I don't see anything counting up, you need to see it counting up while it is inserting, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: display that variable when you finished the loop `label1.text = myint`

Comment: It needs to be displayed while it is inserting (live)

Comment: So why you don't give all the details in your orginal post -_- is it mono thread or are you using single thread

Comment: using singel thread

Comment: then simply add after myint += 2 `label1.text = "Insert Count: "  & myint` please also check this guide since if you don't know how to show a label you should check the basics: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_program_structure.htm

Comment: Thanks man @Mederic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified in the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx), the method ExecuteNonQuery() returns the number of rows affected by your query. This is often used to check that your insert query ended up correctly.

So what you can do is declare an `Integer` somewhere in your code, and increment this integer with the result of the `ExecuteNonQuery()` method call.

At the end, you can update a `Label` with the value of your integer.

Some code:

```
'At the beginning of your update function
Dim myCounter As Integer

'...

'Whenever you run ExecuteNonQuery() on an INSERT statement
myCounter += .ExecuteNonQuery()

'...

'Finally, on the label that should display the result
myLabel.Text = "Updated " & myCounter.toString() & " rows."
```